# How can I access a file in WEB-INF/META-INF in a java web app?

Tags: java, tomcat, classloader

So the book I am reading says:

> Unlike JAR files, the root-level /META-INF directory is not on the
>   application classpath. You cannot use the ClassLoader to obtain
>   resources in this directory. /WEB-INF/classes/META-INF, however, is on
>   the classpath. You can place any application resources you desire in
>   this directory, and they become accessible through the ClassLoader.

And currently under WEB-INF directory I have a META-INF directory and a file called: test.txt.

How can I read this file **using the ClassLoader** ?

I have tried this:

```
URL resource = this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("test.txt");
System.out.println(resource);
```

But this returns null.

I know the file can be read like:

```
InputStream resourceContent = getServletContext().getResourceAsStream("/WEB-INF/META-INF/test.txt");
System.out.println(resourceContent);
```

but this is not I want. I want to understand the ClassLoader..

Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try using this:

```
URL resource=this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("META-INF/test.txt");
```

as your /META-INF is in your root path you will have to use META-INF/test.txt to access it.

Answer (score 4):

> And currently under WEB-INF directory I have a META-INF directory

Then you've done it wrong. Read your own quotation. It says WEB-INF/classes/META-INF.

```
URL resource = this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("test.txt");
```

That should be:

```
URL resource = this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("META-INF/test.txt");
```

Answer (score 0):

If you put the text file right inside your WEB-INF, you could do this,

```
InputStream inputStream = this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("../test.txt");
```

In your case, since your text file is inside the META-INF folder which is inside WEB-INF, you can access the text file like so,

```
InputStream inputStream = this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("../META-INF/test.txt");
```